# Is there a better way to display content depending on the route?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

There is a component responsible for rendering items in the e-commerce. I want to have a single component, which will render different content depending on the category clicked by user.
My solution looks something like this:

```
function ProductsPage({collections}) {
  return (
        <Route path="/products/type_one" render={() =>   
            <div>
                <h1>Type One</h1>
                <div className="products">
                {
                    collections.category.typeOne.items.map((item) => {
                        return (
                            <ProductCard key={item.id} item={item} />
                        )
                    })
                }
                </div>
            </div>
        }/> 

        <Route path="/products/type_two" render={() =>   
            <div>
                <h1>Type Two</h1>
                <div className="products">
                {
                    collections.category.typeTwo.items.map((item) => {
                        return (
                            <ProductCard key={item.id} item={item} />
                        )
                    })
                }
                </div>
            </div>
        }/> 
      )
    }
```

So far I have only four subcategories, that`s why it looks pretty harmless. But if there are dozens of them, then the component code will be clogged with an endless copy-paste. Is there a more elegant method for solving the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [route props](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Route.md#route-props) to dynamically get the category parameter from the route URL and display the items using so. Your code might look similar to this:

```
<Route path="/products/:category" component={Category} />

function Category(props) {
  const category = collections.category[props.match.params.category]

  if (category) {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>category.name</h1>
        <div className="products">
          {
            category.items.map((item) => {
              return (
                <ProductCard key={item.id} item={item} />
              )
            })
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  } else {
    // category does not exist
  }

}
```